# VB.NET Why does this regex return false?

Tags: vb.net, select

I have a function like this one, where I read in a filename, and depending if the filename contains "ABC","123DEF","123HIJ", or "123KLM"... I want to check it with regex and return a true value.

Here is an example of how I am using my regex in that function without posting all the noise.

```
Sub testFooBar()
        Dim testReg As New Regex("(ABC|123ABC|123DEF|123HIJ|123KLM)")
        
        Select Case "ABC"
            Case testReg.IsMatch("123ABC")
        End Select
End Sub
```

I also tried `(ABC|123(ABC|DEF|HIJ))` because my results could be like these:

```
ABC
123ABC
123DEF
123HIJ
```

I think that returns two groups and what I think I need is to return one group. I just don't understand why it's not finding a match if anybody can help me understand. Maybe I should be using something like .Contains() instead. I'm just using regex because that's how I started my function and now I'd like to understand the problem.

The exact problem is the code under `Case testReg.IsMatch("ABC")` wont run because the match is returning false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here isn't really a Regex issue:

You have a case statement, where you are trying to match a string to boolean.  That's causing your issue.  I recommend this syntax as an alternative, or you could just use an IF statement.

```
    Dim testReg As New Regex("(ABC|123ABC|123DEF|123HIJ)")
    
    Select Case True
        Case testReg.IsMatch("123ABC")
            Console.WriteLine("HERE")
    End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above your `Regex` isn't the issue, but rather the `Select Case`.
 If you need to know what was successful from your regex as from what I can see, it could be multiple values, you could return a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples),
Something like this might help getting your started.

```
Function TestFooBar(ByVal input As String) As (Success As Boolean, Output As String)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(input))

    Dim pattern As String = "(ABC|123ABC|123DEF|123HIJ)"
    Dim match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options:=RegexOptions.None)

    Return (match.Success, match.Value)

End Function
```

And to call it

```
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim foo = TestFooBar("ABC")

    If foo.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine($"Value Found Was {foo.Output}")
    End If

End Sub
```

Of Course in this example the `Output` value is the `Input` but from more complex strings, it should help with knowing what was found or not.